# get node names in an XML string with ExtractValue?

Tags: mysql, xml, stored-procedures, xpath

Is it possible in MySQL to get the node names in an XML ?

I use the following in a stored procedure to iterate nodes of an XML, but with this I can only get the values, not the node names :

```
DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 1;
DECLARE nrows INT DEFAULT 1;
DECLARE rownum INT DEFAULT 1;
DECLARE vTag VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT '';
DECLARE returnvalue TEXT DEFAULT '';

DECLARE paramXML TEXT DEFAULT '<fields><a>1</a><b>2</b><c>3</c></fields>';

SET nrows = ExtractValue(paramXML, 'count(//fields/*)');
SET rownum = 1;

WHILE rownum <= nrows DO
  SET vTag= ExtractValue(paramXML, '//fields/*[$rownum]');

    SET returnvalue=CONCAT(returnvalue, vTag, ';');

  SET rownum = rownum + 1;
END WHILE;

SELECT returnvalue;
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL currently only has very basic XML handling functions.  As documented under [`ExtractValue(xml_frag, xpath_expr)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/xml-functions.html#function_extractvalue):

> #### Important
>
> [`ExtractValue()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/xml-functions.html#function_extractvalue) returns only `CDATA`, and does not return any tags that might be contained within a matching tag, nor any of their content (see the result returned as `val1` in the following example).

You could instead install a suitable UDF, such as [MyXML](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/71336/MySQL-XML-User-Defined-Functions).