# how to select a particular node from xml file using node's name and a specific attribute value?

Tags: mysql, sql, xml

i have a MySQL DB in which i have created a table with a **longtext** column in which i store xml files as a string so i am asking if it is possible to get nodes using their names and a specific attribute value!
here is an example of xml i deal with :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="yes" ?>
<HWData>
  <Header time="2013-05-29T13:39:34" uploaded="true" version="1.0" />
  <NE vendorName="Nokia Siemens Networks" NEId="WBTS-431">
    <EQHO vendorName="Nokia Siemens Networks" equipmentHolderId="173" >
        <UNIT vendorName="N" unitId="16" />
        <UNIT vendorName="NOKIA SIEMENS NETWORKS" unitId="225" />
    </EQHO>
    <EQHO vendorName="NSN" equipmentHolderId="40192" >
        <UNIT vendorName="AR" unitId="40267" />
    </EQHO>
  </NE>
  <NE vendorName="Nokia Siemens Networks" NEId="WBTS-261">
    <EQHO vendorName="Nokia Siemens Networks" equipmentHolderId="132" >
      <EQHO vendorName="Nokia Siemens Networks" equipmentHolderId="132-1">
        <UNIT vendorName="NN" unitId="1621" />
      </EQHO>
    </EQHO>
  </NE>
</HWData>
```

is possible to use "EQHO" ( node name ) and "NE-RNC-4/DN:NE-WBTS-4204/EQHO-173" ( value of attribute MOID ) to get this as result using SQL query ! :

```
   <NE vendorName="Nokia Siemens Networks" NEId="WBTS-261">
    <EQHO vendorName="Nokia Siemens Networks" equipmentHolderId="132" >
      <EQHO vendorName="Nokia Siemens Networks" equipmentHolderId="132-1">
        <UNIT vendorName="NN" unitId="1621" />
      </EQHO>
    </EQHO>
   </NE>
```

can someone put me on the right way to achieve that..any other suggestions or example will be appreciated. 
thanks in advance

Comment: Search for `java xml parsing` using a search engine of your choice.

Comment: hi @fabian i am asking if there is way to get the resault using SQL query !!

Comment: Just to clarify you want to pull the any xml node using mysql without knowing the structure ? Do you know the node names ?

Comment: yes @KennethClark i know the node names!

Comment: There is an answer here to MySQL http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21055122/get-node-names-in-an-xml-string-with-extractvalue .. This however may not suit your needs as it requires changes to the MySQL server

Comment: i appreciate your help @KennethClark but it is not what i am looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i used this method to get the node as a string and it is working fine :

```
public static String NodeToString(String file,String moid) throws   SAXException, IOException, ParserConfigurationException{
    String stringNode="";


    InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(file.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"));
    Document doc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(in);
    NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("*");
    for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
        if(nodeList.item(i) instanceof Element && ((Element)nodeList.item(i)).getAttribute("MOID").equalsIgnoreCase(moid)){

    try
    {

      // Set up the output transformer
      TransformerFactory transfac = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
      Transformer trans = transfac.newTransformer();
      trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
      trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");

      // Print the DOM node

      StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
      StreamResult result = new StreamResult(sw);
      DOMSource source = new DOMSource(nodeList.item(i));
      trans.transform(source, result);
      stringNode = sw.toString();

      //System.out.println(xmlString);
    }
    catch (TransformerException e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }       


        }
}
    return stringNode;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

MySQL has a very limited functionality when it comes to querying XML data. There is [`ExtractValue()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/xml-functions.html#function_extractvalue) function which can be used to get node/attribute value from XML document, but it can't return subtree.

Your best bet might be using xpath in the host language of your choice instead. Xpath to get particular node by node's name and specific attribute value according to the example in question would be as follow :

```
//EQHO[@MOID="NE-RNC-4/DN:NE-WBTS-4204/EQHO-173"]
```

Above xpath return all `<EQHO>` elements anywhere in the XML document which have `MOID` attribute value equals `"NE-RNC-4/DN:NE-WBTS-4204/EQHO-173"`. You can even achieve the same without knowing the attribute name, if you want, by replacing `@MOID` with `@*`.

Comment: hi @har07 thanks for replying  i forgot to say that i am dealing with xml files that i don't know their structure in advance so xpath will not help in my case but i have found another solution to do that..i'll post it as response

Comment: @HayderHenchiri I think xpath still applicable. You can achieve the same without knowing the element name with xpath too : `//*[@MOID="NE-RNC-4/DN:NE-WBTS-4204/EQHO-173"]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use xpath.

```
/HWData/NE/EQHO[@MOID="NE-RNC-4/DN:NE-WBTS-4204/EQHO-173"]
```

Sample java code

```
  InputSource is = new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)) ;
  Document doc = builder.parse(is);
  XPathFactory xPathfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
  XPath xpath = xPathfactory.newXPath();
  XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("/HWData/NE/EQHO[@MOID=\"NE-RNC-4/DN:NE-WBTS-4204/EQHO-173\"]");
  NodeList nl = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
  for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++)
  {
    Node node =  nl.item(i);
    System.out.println(nl.item(i).getNodeName());
  }
```

Comment: hi @Kenneth XPath will not work in my case because i am dealing with xml files that i don't know their structure in advance,, the xml that i have posted is  just an example